# Angular 5 CICD with Gitlab

Tags: angular5, gitlab

I am new to CICD, using gitlab to perform cicd.
How to configure  .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Below is my  .gitlab-ci.yml code.,

```
image: node:8.11.1

stages:
  - build 

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

install_dependencies:
  stage: build
  script:
     - npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.6
     - npm install
     - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng start
     - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build
```

i am getting errors like below

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    /root/.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm  --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@5.6.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm

### ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

$ ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve open

### /bin/bash: line 74: ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng: No such file or directory

Comment: please format your code as code

Comment: Is Angular CLI installed globally? Try `npm install -g @angular/cli`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that might be at help

Replace `name-of-my-project` with your project name

```yml
image: node:8.11.1

pages:
  cache:
    paths:
    - node_modules/

  stage: deploy
  script:
  - npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.6
  - npm install
  - ng build --prod --base-href /name-of-my-project/
  - mkdir public
  - mv prod/name-of-my-project/* public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - public
  only:
  - master
```